# What is the benefit of Accept Culture change?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

Maybe the first question should be: what is the impact of the "Accept Culture change"? Does it only change country culture or culture of ALL provinces?

If that only change main culture... what is the benefit of Accept Culture change at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accept Cultural Shift is a good decision to take if you are a small nation that is expanding into a different culture group than your own, because you can move the capital, accept a cultural shift, and then you no longer suffer from the penalties to tax and manpower and rebellion from being a different culture. The decision changes the culture of your nation's government, not the culture of any particular province.

For example if you are playing as a greek OPM and expanding primarily into italy, you can change culture to italian. This means you don't have to spend time and points on converting all the italian provinces to greek. Instead you just convert your original province to italian.

Comment: Thanks, but stability price you pay for that is TOO high. Do you think that would be reasonable to change the culture?

Comment: When you are stable the stability cost is essentially a price in monarch points which you would be paying to convert the provinces anyway. changing is situationally useful as you take a short term penalty instead of a long term one.

Answer (score 2):

Here you can read more about cultures: http://www.eu4wiki.com/Culture#Accepted_cultures

Brief: if provinces with some foreign culture contribute more than 20% of your base tax, then the culture becomes an accepted culture and you get no manpower and tax penalties.

The article about cultural shift: http://www.eu4wiki.com/Decisions#Accept_Cultural_Shift

This decision is available only when the culture of your capital is different from your main culture. It is not just replace culture in one province, it changes the main culture of your entire nation. You don't have to take this decision, you can change the culture of you capital province instead with diplo points.

Answer (score 0):

Provinces with unaccepted cultures get (iirc) -33% reductions to tax and manpower, as well as +2 to province unrest.

Accepting a culture does not change your primary culture - it only means you have enough of it to get the full use out of it.

Comment: Thanks Sunspawn, but what you mean 'enough of it'? If I can accept new culture ... does it mean that FURTHER I will only promote new culture? The price of making cultural shift is 5 stability points... which is quite a lot to just replace culture.

Comment: It is a binary value - either you accept it or you don't. Regular value is 20% of your total base tax, which is lowered by various modifiers - Humanist ideas have an idea that lowers it by 50% to just 10%(as in, 50% out of 20%, thus 10% less) of you basetax, Polish traditions and the first Ottoman idea lower it by 15% (from 20% to 17%).

Comment: Also, once a culture is less than half of the acceptance threshold (if it's unmodified 20%, then once it is less than 10%), you lose that culture as accepted.